# Remove duplicated plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to show a plot, but it was so small, so i decided to use:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,12))
```

in my code:

```
def draw(selected):
    open_plants=[]

    plt.figure(figsize=(20,12))

    for (i,j) in selected:
      for (y,z) in plants_points:       
        if plants_points.index((y,z))==i:
          open_plants.append((y,z))
        else:
          plt.plot([p[0] for p in plants_points], [p[1] for p in plants_points], 'kx')

    open_plants2=list(set(open_plants)) 
    for (element1,element2) in open_plants2:
      plt.plot(element1,element2,'bs')

    plt.plot([p[0] for p in customers_points], [p[1] for p in customers_points], 'ro', label='Customers')

    for (i,j) in selected:     
      for k in num_list:
        if i==k:
          plt.plot([plants_points[i][0],customers_points[j][0]], [plants_points[i][1],customers_points[j][1]], color_list[k], label='facility %i'%i)



    plt.xlabel("X coordinate")
    plt.ylabel("Y coordinate")
    plt.title('Uncapacitated Facility Location Problem')
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.075, 1), title='Legend', loc='upper right')
    plt.tight_layout()
draw({})
```

But when i call draw(selected) it shows 2 plots and not 1. How can i fix it?

Comment: Did you already create a figure outside your function? `plt.figure(figsize=(20,12))` will "forget" the existing figure and create a new one.  If you already created a figure earlier, you can call `fig.set_size_inches(20,12)` on it.  (f you didn't save the fig, you can retrieve it via `fig = plt.gcf()` ("get current figure").

Comment: Thanks for answer! That was the problem!